# How to handle the apple callback in Parse Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, apple-sign-in

I have the Sign in with apple working to the point that I'm signed in with apple and apple redirects with a Post request to my server.

I set up the following express post handler:

```
app.post('/apple-callback', async function (req, res) {
    let data = req.body.id_token
    let buff = Buffer.from(data.split('.')[1], 'base64')
    let text = buff.toString('utf8')
    let json = JSON.parse(text)
    try {
        let currentUser = await Parse.User.logInWith('apple', {
            'authData':{
                'id': json.sub,
                'token': data
            } 
        })

        console.info(currentUser)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

    res.json({
        'fissa': req.body,
        'state': req.body.state,
        'code': req.body.code,
        'idToken': req.body.id_token,
        json,
        sub: json.sub
    })
})
```

but I get the following error:

```
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
Uncaught internal server error. { JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' } JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signatureJsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
Uncaught internal server error. { JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' } JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signatureJsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
Uncaught internal server error. { JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' } JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signatureJsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
Uncaught internal server error. { JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'invalid signature' } JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Feb 25, 2020, 15:56:39 +01:00- ERROR
JsonWebTokenError: invalid signatureJsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
    at /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:133:19
    at getSecret (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyIdToken (/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sashido-parse-server-apple-auth-adapter/index.js:43:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Any suggestions?

This is how far I got with [parse docs](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#apple-authdata) and some trial and error.

But I don't know how to fix the errors and get a valid parse user.

Comment: Why not use `const json = JSON.parse(atob(data.split(".")[1])).sub`?

Comment: as far as I know atob is not available in node. so I use a buffer to base64decode

Comment: OK. Might not matter, but atob would imply decoding to ascii.  Have you tried that? `buff.toString('ascii')`

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that, sadly changing it does not change the errors I get.

Comment: @stephan I have the exact same error using parse and apple sign in. Did you already manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @dndr kind of... I figured out that it works better if you use Parse.User.logInWith client side. so I redirect the correct values back to the user (i'm not sure if this is safe.. but it works)

Comment: @stephan See my issue on github here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6496. Apple sign in is not working correctly in the current version of parse-server. It has been merged into master, so we chose to deploy that specific commit, but I think the fix will be released soon.

Comment: @dndr awesome that explains why it only worked some of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out there was a bug in parse-server, apple started hosting more than one public key (so the key did not always match with the signed jwt), which was not supported by the authentication adapter. By now, the fix is merged into master and will be shipped with the next release, at which point the code I used in my question works.

fyi: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/6496